# How to parallely `map(...)` on a custom, single-threaded iterator in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, rust

I have a `MyReader` that implements `Iterator` and produces `Buffer`s where `Buffer : Send`. `MyReader` produces a lot of `Buffer`s very quickly, but I have a CPU-intensive job to perform on each `Buffer` (`.map(|buf| ...)`) that is my bottleneck, and then gather the results (ordered). I want to parallelize the CPU intense work - hopefully to N threads, that would use work stealing to perform them as fast as the number of cores allows.

Edit: To be more precise. I am working on [`rdedup`](https://github.com/dpc/rdedup). `MyStruct` is `Chunker` which reads `io::Read` (typically stdio), finds parts (chunks) of data and yields them. Then `map()` is supposed, for each chunk, to calculate sha256 digest of it, compress, encrypt, save and return the digest as the result of `map(...)`. Digest of saved data is used to build `index` of the data. The order between chunks being processed by  `map(...)` does not matter, but digest returned from each `map(...)` needs to be collected in the same order that the chunks were found. The actual `save` to file step is offloaded to yet another thread (writter thread). [actual code of PR in question](https://github.com/dpc/rdedup/pull/84/files#diff-088084dd1b0c42eef28a4a1352b0e72aR795)

I hoped I can use [`rayon`](http://docs.rs/rayon/) for this, but `rayon` expect an iterator that is already parallizable - eg. a `Vec<...>` or something like that. I have found no way to get a `par_iter` from `MyReader` - my reader is very single-threaded in nature.

There is [`simple_parallel`](https://github.com/huonw/simple_parallel) but documentation says it's not recommended for general use. And I want to make sure everything will just work.

I could just take a spmc queue implementation and a custom `thread_pool`, but I was hopping for an existing solution that is optimized and tested.

There's also [`pipeliner`](https://docs.rs/pipeliner) but doesn't support ordered map yet.

Comment: We're missing a few things here: (1) what should the result be like (does your task emit something on stdout? write a file? return something) and (2) does order of execution matter or not?

Comment: If the iterator is quick to produce content, but it takes time to process them, a reasonable workaround is to collect elements into small vectors and process those with Rayon's `par_iter()`. It would be better if Rayon supported this natively, though, as parallel processing of items coming from a stream is a frequently needed feature.

Comment: @user4815162342: Hmmm... interesting, but it seems to me it would put unnecessary delay on reading thread, that would for each batch to completed, and I'm really looking for full CPU utilization.

Comment: @dpc.pw Yes; the suggestion was tied to the assumption that the iterator is quick to produce content, and that processing is the bottle-neck, as was my understanding based on the second sentence of your question. If this is not the case, then batching would indeed introduce reading delays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, preserving order is a pretty tough requirement as far as parallelization goes.

You could try to hand-make it with a typical fan-out/fan-in setup:

- a single producer which tags inputs with a sequential monotonically increasing ID,
- a thread pool which consumes from this producer and then sends the result toward the final consumer,
- a consumer who buffers and reorders result so as to treat them in the sequential order.

Or you could raise the level of abstraction.

---

Of specific interest here: `Future`.

A `Future` represents the result of a computation, which may or may not have happened yet. A consumer receiving an ordered list of `Future` can simply wait on each one, and let buffering occur naturally in the queue.

For bonus points, if you use a fixed size queue, you automatically get back-pressure on the consumer.

---

And therefore I would recommend building something of [`CpuPool`](https://docs.rs/futures-cpupool/latest/futures_cpupool/struct.CpuPool.html).

The setup is going to be:

```
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};

fn produce(sender: Sender<...>) {
    let pool = CpuPool::new_num_cpus();

    for chunk in reader {
        let future = pool.spawn_fn(|| /* do work */);
        sender.send(future);
    }

    // Dropping the sender signals there's no more work to consumer
}

fn consume(receiver: Receiver<...>) {
    while let Ok(future) = receiver.recv() {
        let item = future.wait().expect("Computation Error?");

        /* do something with item */
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    std::thread::spawn(move || consume(receiver));

    produce(sender);
}
```

Comment: I went with a thread-pool taking jobs tagged with number, through mpmc channel, and sending results through another channel. Results are collected to vector that is then sorted by the job number.I'm not fully satisfied with it, but it will do for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a [dpc-pariter](https://crates.io/crates/dpc-pariter) crate. Simply replace `iter.map(fn)` with `iter.parallel_map(fn)`, which will perform work in parallel while preserving result order.  From the docs:

```
* drop-in replacement for standard iterators(*)
  * preserves order
  * lazy, somewhat like single-threaded iterators
  * panic propagation
* support for iterating over borrowed values using scoped threads
* backpressure
* profiling methods (useful for analyzing pipelined processing bottlenecks)
```

Also, Rayon has an [open issue](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/210) with a great in-depth discussion of various implementation details and limitations.